# How can I find domain that has been used from a client to reach my server in python socket?

Tags: python

I just wonder how apache server can know the domain you come from you can see that in Vhost configuration

Answer (score 0):

By a reverse DNS lookup of the IP; `socket.gethostbyaddr()`.

Results vary; many IPs from consumer ISPs won't resolve to anything interesting, because of NAT and just not maintaining a generally informative reverse zone.

Comment: Thanks bro but you miss understand me !!! I mean my server can have multiple domain point to the same ip in my server for exemple i have many websites when a client visit a domain i wanna know what is that domain to redirect him to the appropriate website

Comment: The `Host` HTTP header then.